# How to reference a custom value file for sub-charts in helm?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-deployment

I have been implementing helm sub-chart by referring [helm sub chart documentation](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals.md). According to the documentation it worked for me. This works fine with default value files. But when I try to refer my own value file, the values are not there in the configmap.
My value file is values.staging.yaml.

eg :-

config.yaml in mysubchart

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
    name: {{ .Release.Name }}-configmap
data:
    salad: {{ .Values.dessert }}
```

values.staging.yaml in mysubchart

```
dessert: banana
```

values.yaml in mysubchart

```
dessert: cake
```

Only 'cake' is referenced as the value. I need to reference banana as the value.

I have tried following commands.

1. helm install --dry-run --debug mychart --values mychart/charts/mysubchart/values.staging.yaml
2. helm install --dry-run --debug --name mychart mychart -f mychart/charts/mysubchart/values.staging.yaml
3. helm install --name mychart mychart -f mychart/charts/mysubchart/values.staging.yaml

In each instance the configmap does not refer the value in the values.staging.yaml.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you .!

Comment: Can you add an example to the question?  In the values file you're trying to use, are the keys you're trying to set under a top-level key that's the name of the subchart?

Comment: I have edited question adding an example @DavidMaze

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in [Overriding Values of a Child Chart](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/#overriding-values-from-a-parent-chart) in your link, you need to wrap the subchart values in a key matching the name of the subchart.

Any values file you pass with `helm install -f` is always interpreted at the top level, even if it's physically located in a subchart's directory.  A typical values file could look like

```
mysubchart:
  dessert: banana
```