# Can I have multiple values.yaml(with different names) for helm sub charts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a parent chart and sub chart with different values(Have an use-case while working with different environments). my use is in such a way when I deploy parent chart, Subchart with mentioned yaml (maybe defined in parent chart) should get deployed.

Comment: I am afraid that it is not possible. Please take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57025334/how-to-reference-a-custom-value-file-for-sub-charts-in-helm

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example of what you need?  You can provide both parent and subchart configuration together in the same `helm install -f` values file; there's no way to do any sort of computation or processing on the values that get passed to subcharts.

Comment: @DavidMaze the use case is pretty simple: say you have a generic/universal helm chart (as advised by, say, Devops Nirvana). You use this universal chart as subchart for your microservices charts. Now, since there can be hundreds of microservices charts, you want to define a default "dev" values.yaml in universal chart, with some sane defaults for your env, that microservices can consume.

It is very disappointing that helm doesn't support this.